# How to delete entries via SafeCracker

Tags: channel-entries, safecracker

How do people go about deleting entries via SafeCracker? I've got an extranet where I'd like to allow staff admins to delete entries, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

I've searched around and one suggestion is to set the entry status to 'closed' in order to fake the deletion, whilst another is to check out this third party add-on: [Delete Entries and Comments](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/delete-entries-and-comments).

Just wondering if there's any other ideas or suggestions for this? I'm not sure if the above add-on will do the job for me (as it says it only allows users to delete *their own entries*, not allow 'admin' users to *delete other user's entries*), and setting the status to 'closed' seems like a last resort type of workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin "Delete entries and comments" uses the channel API for deleting the entries so it respects the logged in member's group preferences. 
It would be fine for you to set the member's preferences for deleting entries from Control Panel according to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this, Bhashkar. I'll give it a try as it sounds like it may do just as I want after all! :)